# Sum different elements of a vector into a new vector without using a for loop? (R programming)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I need to take an existing vector and create a new vector that contains the values;

```
(x1+2x2−x3, x2+2x3−x4, . . . , xn−2+2xn−1 − xn)
```

I've tried using `xVec[n-2] + 2* xVec[n-1] - xVec[n]`  but this doesn't work!

Comment: It would help to make this reproducible: real R vectors with sample data, and your expected output given that sample data.

Comment: In other languages you can reshape the vector to have a length bigger by 2, adding one 0 at each end in a copy, 2 zeros at the end or 2 at the beginning in the other copies, and then you just have to sum (*2 and subtract) the 3 copies. I guess it can also be done in R !?

Comment: @B.Go There are functions in R available which shift the elements of a vector to the right ("lag") or to the left ("lead").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `zoo`:

```
n <- 10
xVec <- seq(n)
idx <- seq(1, n-2)
xVec[idx] + 2* xVec[idx+1] - xVec[idx+2]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a *rolling calculation*, something that the `zoo` package provides:

```r
vec <- 1:10
zoo::rollapply(vec, width = 3, FUN = function(z) z[1]+2*z[2]-z[3])
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
```

Validation, using first three and last three:

```r
1 + 2*2 - 3
# [1] 2
8 + 2*9 - 10
# [1] 16
```

Explanation: each time the function (passed to `FUN=`) is called, it is given a vector with `width=` elements in it. The first call is effectively `z=1:3`, the second call `z=2:4`, third `z=3:5`, etc.

You should know that by default it will return `length(vec) - width + 1` elements in its return value. You can control this with `fill=` and `align=` arguments:

```r
zoo::rollapply(1:10, width = 3, FUN = function(z) z[1]+2*z[2]-z[3], fill = NA)
#  [1] NA  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 NA
zoo::rollapply(1:10, width = 3, FUN = function(z) z[1]+2*z[2]-z[3], fill = NA, align = "right")
#  [1] NA NA  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
```

Answer (score 1):

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846485/sum-different-elements-of-a-vector-into-a-new-vector-without-using-a-for-loop#comment103967013_58846485), [B. Go](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10496710/b-go) has suggested to "reshape" the vector and wonders if this can be done in R as well.

In R, two packages provide functions to shift the elements of a vector: `data.table` and `dplyr`. (The `lag()` function from base R deals with times series objects.)

#### data.table

```
x <- 1:10
library(data.table)
shift(x, 2L) + 2 * shift(x) - x
```

> ```
> [1] NA NA  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
> ```

#### dplyr

```
x <- 1:10
library(dplyr)
lag(x, 2L) + 2 * lag(x) - x
```

> ```
> [1] NA NA  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
> ```

---

By default, both functions do fill up missing values after shifting with `NA`. This explains why the first two elements of the result vector are NA.

To get rid of the leading `NA`s, the `tail()` function can be used, e.g.,

```
tail(shift(x, 2L) + 2 * shift(x) - x, -2L)
```

> ```
> [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are up for a bit of matrix math:

```
xVec <- 1:10
linear_combo <- c(1, 2, -1)

m <- matrix(0, length(xVec), length(xVec))
for (index in seq_along(linear_combo)) {
  m[row(m) == col(m) - index + 1] <- linear_combo[index]
}

m %*% xVec
```

Note in this case the last two elements are incomplete and should probably be dropped or replaced by NA.

```
head(m %*% xVec, -(length(linear_combo) - 1))
```